# Make React Native Elements ButtonGroup swipeable

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want some guidance how to make it possible to swipe between react native elements "Buttongroups".

I found a "swiper" library but cant make it work with the buttongroup.
https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper

Have anyone any idé how to implement this ?
I want to be able to both swipe and push one of the buttons.

My Component including ButtonGroup :

```
class Users extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
      selectedIndex: 0,
      loading: false
    }
    this.updateIndex = this.updateIndex.bind(this)
  }

  // Call fetchList with 0 to get access to all users

  componentWillMount () {
    let i = 0
    this.props.fetchList(i)
    this.props.fetchProfileData()
  }

  // updates the selectedIndex and calls the methods with the selectedindex

  updateIndex (selectedIndex) {
    this.setState({selectedIndex})
    this.fetchAllUsers(selectedIndex)
    this.fetchFemale(selectedIndex)
    this.fetchMale(selectedIndex)
  }

  fetchAllUsers (index) {
    if (index === 0) {
      this.props.fetchList(index)
    }
  }
  fetchFemale (index) {
    if (index === 1) {
      this.props.fetchList(index)
    }
  }

  fetchMale (index) {
    if (index === 2) {
      this.props.fetchList(index)
    }
  }

  renderItem ({ item }) {
    return <ListUserItem user={item} />
  }

  render () {
    const buttons = ['All', 'Female', 'Male']
    const { selectedIndex } = this.state
    return (

      <ImageBackground
        source={require('../../assets/image.jpg')}
        style={styles.container}
         >

        <HeaderBlack />

        <View>
          <BlurView
            style={styles.absolute}
            blurType='dark'
            blurAmount={0.001}
            height={695} />

          <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }} >

            <ButtonGroup
              onPress={this.updateIndex.bind(this)}
              selectedIndex={selectedIndex}
              selectedButtonStyle={{backgroundColor: 'black'}}
              buttons={buttons}
              containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent', height: 23, width: 200, marginTop: 30, marginBottom: -20, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'baseline' }}
              textStyle={{fontFamily: 'GeosansLight', color: 'white'}} />

          </View>

          <View style={{ maxHeight: 580, marginTop: 50 }} >

            <FlatList
              data={this.props.users}
              renderItem={this.renderItem}
           />

          </View>
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>

    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [hammer.js](https://hammerjs.github.io/) for any swipe interactions I need to manage. Essentially this library just has you create custom event listeners for things like swiping, panning, pinching, rotating, etc. and just attach them to whatever element you'd like. As long as you have a reference to the element, it shouldn't matter if it is a react element or not, it should work just the same.